# Current version of Google Charts (v49) breaks my google sheet table visualization, while v48 works fine. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-visualization

I seem to have the problem with the current version of google charts (v49) that it breaks the HTML-visualization of the google sheets table on a website, while the code works fine with v48.

I suspect this to be due to the following change according to Google release notes: "The JSON response option now requires that the server returns strict JSON."

However, I don't understand why my boilerplate(?) html code is not working under v49 (or why it is not returning strict JSON in compliance with v49). I have not read about anyone else having this issue and I really would like to know how to update my code so that it runs with the most current (and future) versions of google charts.

In the following sniplet, changing

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['table']});
```

to

```
google.charts.load('48', {packages: ['table']});
```

makes it run without any problems.

**My question: How to change my code so that it works with v49.**

```html
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

var visualization;

function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p5feKZEBdCxoS3XDfxVjZu0zY4v3QpVYCgFbctwxlEA/edit?usp=sharing');
    query.setQuery('SELECT A, K, C');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('There was a problem with your query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
    visualization.draw(data);
}

</script>

</head>
<body id="background">
  <div id="table"><h2>Please, wait. Google's visualization is obviously a bit slow at the moment...</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? (Your code works fine on Chrome)

Comment: Both chrome and firefox give me the error. I even get an error if I run the code snippet here on stackoverflow, using the "run code snippet"! So I am now very confused that you do not get the error.

Comment: You can't run the XHR from an i-frame due to the restricted CORS policy. That's why it will time out. How are you setting up the environment to run the code in your local browser?